# Creating Loops for Cube numbers in Python

Tags: python

I'm very new to python and coding, been given some exercises to try and complete and there's one that I just can't get, it's not essential to have it solved but not knowing is annoying me so much. I have to create a loop of the first 10 cube numbers I've been able to do this with square numbers and I tried to use the same process but it's not working

```
Cubes=[]
for i in range((11)):
   Cubes.append(i**3)
```

But all I'm getting is -

```
 runfile('C:/Users/Hannah/Cubes.py', wdir='C:/Users/Hannah')
```

What am I doing wrong

Comment: Did you ever run a python script on your engine ? Have you tried a simple "Hello world"? It could be that your code is working, just not displaying the result.  The cryptic line you observe is just python telling you that they are executing your script

Comment: Why do you think you are doing something wrong?

Comment: What's the actual error you're seeing? How are you running your script? are you sure you're not missing a print statement somewhere? I think adding those details would help us help you :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want numbers to show on your screen you should use something like this:

```
Cubes=[]
for i in range((11)):
    Cubes.append(i**3)
print(Cubes)
```

or

```
Cubes=[]
for i in range((11)):
    Cubes.append(i**3)
    print(i**3)
```

Try to note the difference. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

First, you forgot to print it. Second good job.

```
def Cubes
    Cubes=[]
    for i in range(10):
       Cubes.append(i**3)
    print Cubes
```

This is what you want. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

```
maximum = input("Enter Max: ")
r = range(1, maximum)
Cube = maximum * maximum * maximum

for j in r:
  if j * j * j <= Cube:
      print  (j * j * j)
```